# Adding Conditional Clause(Where) to Dense Rank Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, dense-rank, ranking-functions

I want to create an Rank function to count the number of times a person a visited to property `BY DATE` but with condition of not including a visit category. `'Calls'`

```sql
DENSE_RANK() over(partition by activitytable.[Property] 
ORDER BY activitytable.[Date] as Job rank
```

Doing this ranks the whole of the communication table which I dont want.

| ActivityID | Property | DATE | CommunicationType | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1046 | Red Property | 30/10/2019 | Field | 2 |
| 10467 | Red Property | 29/10/2019 | Field | 1 |
| 10591 | Red Property | 28/10/2019 | Calls |  |
| 10971 | Blue Property | 27/10/2019 | Field | 2 |
| 10971 | Blue Property | 26/10/2019 | Field | 1 |
| 10971 | Blue Property | 26/10/2019 | calls |  |
| 10965 | Green Property | 24/10/2019 | calls |  |
| 10765 | Green Property | 23/10/2019 | calls |  |
| 10765 | Green Property | 19/10/2019 | field | 3 |
| 10765 | Green Property | 15/10/2019 | field | 2 |
| 10765 | Green Property | 12/10/2019 | field | 1 |

Ideally I want the table to appear like above to ignoring the calls elements of the communication type column and count only fields category. How could I do this?

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Answer (score 5):

You need to partition by `Property` and `CommunicationType`:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    ActivityID int,
    Property varchar(100),
    [DATE] date,
    CommunicationType varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
    (ActivityID, Property, [DATE], CommunicationType)
VALUES
    (1046,  'Red Property',    '20191030', 'field'),
    (10467, 'Red Property',    '20191029', 'field'),
    (10591, 'Red Property',    '20191028', 'calls'),
    (10971, 'Blue Property',   '20191027', 'field'),
    (10971, 'Blue Property',   '20191026', 'field'),
    (10971, 'Blue Property',   '20191026', 'calls'),
    (10965, 'Green Property',  '20191024', 'calls'),
    (10765, 'Green Property',  '20191023', 'calls'),
    (10765, 'Green Property',  '20191019', 'field'),
    (10765, 'Green Property',  '20191015', 'field'),
    (10765, 'Green Property',  '20191012', 'field')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN CommunicationType = 'field' THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Property, CommunicationType ORDER BY [DATE] ASC)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Rank
FROM #Data
```

Result:

```
ActivityID  Property    DATE        CommunicationType   Rank
10971   Blue Property   2019-10-26  calls               NULL
10971   Blue Property   2019-10-26  field               1
10971   Blue Property   2019-10-27  field               2
10765   Green Property  2019-10-23  calls               NULL
10965   Green Property  2019-10-24  calls               NULL
10765   Green Property  2019-10-12  field               1
10765   Green Property  2019-10-15  field               2
10765   Green Property  2019-10-19  field               3
10591   Red Property    2019-10-28  calls               NULL
10467   Red Property    2019-10-29  field               1
1046    Red Property    2019-10-30  field               2
```

Comment: @shevchenko2020 I hope it helps. If you think that this or any other answer is the best solution to your problem, you may accept it (only one answer can be accepted). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
CASE WHEN CommunicationType <> 'CAlls' THEN DENSE_RANK() over(partition by activitytable.[Property] ORDER BY activitytable.[Date] ELSE NULL END AS Job rank
```

Comment: I think you need to partition by `CommunicationType ` as well.

Comment: @Alex Basically, I just copy the OP clause - the key point here is to use `CASE WHEN` or `IIF` to exclude some of the rows from ranking - the ranking clause may be as he likes.

Comment: I believe you don't exclude rows from ranking this way, you only hide the value in Select i.e. the value is counted in the rank, just not displayed. Same as `CASE ... SUM` is different to `SUM( CASE ...`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, almost works but this doesn't complete ignores the nulls and just skips over it like. 1,2,3 Null, 5 etc

Answer (score 1):

You have no duplicate dates, so just use a cumulative sum:

```
sum(case when communicationtype <> 'Calls'
         then 1 else 0
    end) over (partition by activitytable.[Property] order by activitytable.[Date]
              ) as Job_rank
```

Presumably, you also have a column that represents the "person", if you want this ranking per person.

If you do need `dense_rank()` because there are duplicates, then the answer is more challenging.  The following should do what you want:

```
select (case when communicationtype = 'Visits'
             then dense_rank() over (partition by activitytable.[Property], communicationtype
                                     order by activitytable.[Date]
                                    )
        end) as job_rank
```

Note:  the value will not appear on the rows with `Calls`.  It is not clear if that is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it works. The key thing here is to add the communication type to the partition by with the case when statement. Cheers